# throttle a react event handler in a dumb-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm trying to buffer the user input and once the user didn't press any key for 1 second, I intend to perform `sendRequest()`. But this isn't working. Instead, it invokes `sendRequest()` every time user presses any key.

I appreciate any comments/possible fixes.

```
import React from 'react';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

const ELAPSED_TIME = 1000;    

const App = ({ setInputTerm, ...props }) => {
  const onHandleQueryChange = (e) => {
    setInputTerm(e.target.value);
    throttledSendRequest();  
  };

  function sendRequest() {
    console.log('hey you');
  }

  const throttledSendRequest = throttle(sendRequest, ELAPSED_TIME);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={onHandleQueryChange} type="text"></input>
    </div>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce):

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced function was invoked. The debounced function comes with a cancel method to cancel delayed func invocations and a flush method to immediately invoke them. Provide options to indicate whether func should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the wait timeout. The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the debounced function. Subsequent calls to the debounced function return the result of the last func invocation.

```
import React from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const ELAPSED_TIME = 1000;    

const App = ({ setInputTerm, ...props }) => {
  const onHandleQueryChange = (e) => {
    setInputTerm(e.target.value);
    throttledSendRequest();  
  };

  function sendRequest() {
    console.log('hey you');
  }

  const throttledSendRequest = debounce(sendRequest, ELAPSED_TIME);

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={onHandleQueryChange} type="text"></input>
    </div>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: initially, I used debounce. Once I typed 3 characters, it would wait 1 second, and then run sendRequest() three times. Can you elaborate on why and how to fix it?

Comment: @omid.n You most likely created a copy of the debounce function each time (Perhaps you put it in the onHandleQueryChange, instead of once outside of the function), so it was running 3 separate instances of the debounced function.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I had to move the sendRequest to the top of the file before defining the App component, since it was running on the render() of the component and it would recreate the function every time it renders the App.

Comment: @omid.n Be sure to mark the answer as accepted (The checkmark below the post score), if this solution worked for you.